# Issue With Filter and sort a list Prompt - Python3

Tags: python

Below is the prompt I am having trouble with. I have come up with a solution that pretty much gets the proper output, but with an extra return/new line that should be a space and not a new line. Can anyone see what could be causing the new line?

---

Write a program that gets a list of integers from input, and outputs non-negative integers in ascending order (lowest to highest).
Ex: If the input is:
10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2
the output is:
2 4 10 12 39
For coding simplicity, follow every output value by a space. Do not end with new line.****

---

My Code:

```
#Get Input
user_input = input()
#Split input into individual entries within list
user_list = user_input.split()
map_object = map(int, user_list) 
list_of_integers = list(map_object)
#Remove Negative Values from list
list_of_integers = [i for i in list_of_integers if i >= 0]
#Sort List In Ascending Order
list_of_integers.sort()
#Convert list of integers back into a string
list_of_integers = [str(int) for int in list_of_integers] 
#Join string by a space
str_of_ints =" ".join(list_of_integers)
print(str_of_ints)
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your question first, for example by [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), or following along a tutorial [until you get to the relevant part](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming), or [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+print+without+newline).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the newline from the print you can just do this

```py
print(str_of_ints, end='')  # end character is now empty not \n
```

Comment: Ah, simple. Keep it simple. Thank you that did it!